# How to exit from setValue Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a code for change `messageText` from database entry:

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.edit:
                AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo tm = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                int position = tm.position;
                final DatabaseReference ref = adapter.getRef(position);
                ref.child("messageUserId").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString())) {
                            ref.child("messageText").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    input.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                                    sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            ref.child("messageText").setValue(input.getText().toString());
                                            input.getText().clear();

                                            Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "Изменено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Code `ref.child("messageText").setValue(input.getText().toString())` works excellent, but after it code starts up again from

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     input.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
```

And everything goes in a circle - the data from `messageText` is inserted into the `EditText` `input` and I can again change the text.

**How to stop executing code after first changing `messageText`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right code:

```
      @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo tm = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            int position = tm.position;
            editText = adapter.getRef(position);


            editText.child("messageUserId").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(dataSnapshot.getValue())) {
                        editText.child("messageText").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                input.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                                editMessage();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "Запрещено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
    }
    return true;
}

private void editMessage() {
    sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText.child("messageText").setValue(input.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(Chat.this, "Изменено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            input.getText().clear();
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
}

private void sendMessage() {
    sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (input.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(Chat.this, getString(R.string.edittext_null), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference()
                        .push()
                        .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                                Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getDisplayName(),
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                                payload,
                                avatar,
                                uploadedAttach
                        ));
                input.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It was necessary to simply return to the button its original action and use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead `addValueEventListener`.

Comment: Which is bassicaly the exact answer I provided you, right?

Answer (score 1):

ValueEventListener's [onDataChange()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener.html#onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot)) method:

> This method will be called with a snapshot of the data at this location. It will also be called each time that data changes.

With other words, even if it is a write, an update or even a delete operation, this method is triggered. This is also happening in your case, you're using the same reference `ref.child("messageText")` to add data and also to listen for changes and that's why you have this behaviour. This is happening over and over again. To solve this, you need to change the logic of your code, by creating two different events. onClick to write the data to the database and attach the listener so it cannot be related to that event.

Comment: You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer, and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: Alex, thank you for a hint about another method. I spread the working code.